# Несудимы, не судимы мной

Tags: частица-не

Виктор Астафьев: Анисим Анисимович понимал; не к нему лично ненависть, к тому делу, которое он исполнял, была, есть и всегда пребудет она, ибо еще Он ― Он! ― завещал: «Не судите да несудимы будете!»

Но в Интернете везде: не судите, не судите, да не судимы будете.

По правилам написание НЕ со словами на -мый, образованными 
от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида: 
такие слова могут быть и причастиями (раздельное написание), так и прилагательными (слитное). 
Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется творительный падеж действующего лица, реже творительный орудия (текст, не читаемый мной); 
при наличии других пояснительных слов они становятся прилагательными.

Значит, несудимы, не судимы мной?

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идёт об известной заповеди "Не судите, да не судимы будете"(В Евангелии от Матфея (гл. 7, ст. 1-2) сказано: «Не судите, да не судимы будете, ибо каким судом судите, таким будете судимы; и какою мерою мерите, такою и вам будут мерить»), то здесь явно изложено подчёркнутое  отрицание воздействия (осуждения), потому КРАТКОЕ прилагательное, как и краткое причастие, пишется раздельно.

Однако современные авторы, видимо, считают, что следует писать по основным  правилам, а не по примечанию (различение по смыслу). Но ведь прилагательные судимый и несудимый употребляются в значении характеристики человека по наличию и отсутствию у него судимостей в прошлом, а здесь именно в значении "никем не судимы".
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/1744/%D0%9D%D0%B5

Не судимы мной, конечно, раздельно, это явно причастие.

Answer (score 1):

**А. Ответ**

В Нацкорпусе 85 примеров с раздельным написанием частицы НЕ и 3 примера со слитным написанием , в том числе у Астафьева. **Раздельная форма  явно преобладает, и это неудивительно.**

**Не судите, да не судимы будете. Другими словами: Не судите, да не будете судимы.** 
Здесь инверсия связки "будете" и именной части сказуемого, выраженного кратким прилагательным "судимы". Это и есть причина раздельного написания частицы НЕ.

**Б. Примечание (как мы обычно решаем орфографические задачи)**

Вообще говоря, не стоит подходит к подобным вопросам формально, как это делается обычно.

1) Прежде всего, **обратимся к словарю:**

СУДИТЬ, нсв. 1. (**о ком-чём или с придат. дополнит.**). Составлять, высказывать какое-л. мнение, суждение. С. о книге. **2. кого-что. Оценивать (обычно негативно) чьи-л. дела, поступки**. С. за ошибки. Не судите строго. * **Победителей не судят** (Посл.). Не судите, да не судимы будете (Библия). 3. **кого.** Рассматривать чей-л. проступок, преступление в судебном порядке. С. преступника. 4. (что). Спорт. Следить за соблюдением правил игры и разрешать возникающие споры. С. игру.

2) В современном языке значение "судить кого-то **(перех.)"** в значении  оценивать поступки" практически не используется, следовательно, **и форма "судимый" имеет ограниченное применение (устойчивые изречения, поговорки).**  В этом случае "судимый" - это, безусловно, прилагательное (вспомним, что причастие настоящего времени  должно обозначать действие, протекающее в данный момент).

3) Существует юридические термины: судимый, прежде/ранее судимый,  несудимый, не судим, ранее не судим и т.д., но это другая тема.

**В. Вывод:** 1) не судимы будете (философское изречение), 2) "не судимы мной", в современном языке такое сочетание практически не имеет смысла.